# Matlab crashes when compiling mex with gcc and -mavx

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, avx

I want to use AVX instructions in mex files and compile with -mavx

Here is a really simple mex function and the error occurs here:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    double * out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    *out = 3.0;
}
```

When I compile this using -m64 -O2 and run it using

```
out = myFunction()
```

it runs fine, but if I compile it with an additional -mavx flag matlab crashes when I try to run the code.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          (unknown signal) detected at Sat Jun 14 14:41:54 2014
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : D:\Programme\MATLAB\R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
(unknown signal)
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your CPU does not support AVX ?

Comment: Just an observation: the call doesn't match the definition at all.

Comment: @PaulR Spot on: "Family 6 Model 37" is the Clarkdale subset of Westmere - which only supports up to SSE4.1.

Comment: Yea, you are right, I didn't realise this and apologize for the stupid question. But thanks a lot for helpig me out..:)